# Local Storage and Form in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a div (form) that appears when you click a button,
I need to be able with jquery stored the information of the form.
For technical reasons, I can not use PHP so I turned to localStorage which seems simple, but does not work very well with my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 5;

  $('.addbox').click(function(){ 
      $('.formdiv').removeClass('formdiv');
      $('#formulaire').addClass('formdivdisplay');
  });

  $('#submit').click(function(){
      var titre = $('#titleform').val();
      var chemin = $('#chemin').val();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      var statue = $('#statue').val();
      var side = $('#select').val();

      localStorage.setItem('titre', titre);
      localStorage.setItem('chemin', chemin);
      localStorage.setItem('name', name);
      localStorage.setItem('statue', statue);
      localStorage.setItem('side', side);

      i = i + 1;


 });

    function drawBox(){
       var block = '<div class="boxindex'+ i +'"><h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">'+ localStorage.getItem('titre') +'</h1></div>';

       localStorage.setItem('block', block);     

      $('.container').append(localStorage.getItem('block'));

    }   
});
```

HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>

  <!--  Meta  -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Bienvenue sur SAKADO</title>

  <!--  Styles  -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/nouvelleoutils.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,700|Space+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/cdn/friconix.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

  <!--design-->
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="top">
  <h1 class="h1 animated fadeInRight">SAKADO</h1>
  <div class="divheader">
  <a class="a1 active" href="home.html">Accueil</a>
  <a class="a2" href="demande.html">Demandes</a>
  <a class="a3" href="utilisation.html">Utilisation</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <div class="addbox"><i class="fi-xwsuxl-plus-solid"></i></div>
</div>
  <!--design-->

  <div id="page">
    <p class="tlegend">Les textes en <span class="Svert">Vert</span> sont les chemins d'accès, en <span class="Sorange">Orange</span> des informations importantes.</p>

   <!--Box glossaire-->
   <div class="container"> 
    <div class="box">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">Glossaire du CSG</h1>
      <p class="Sbleu statue">Public</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">V:\Operations\GLOSSAIRE ver07-00 du 071212.pdf</a></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/GLOSSAIRE ver07-00 du 071212.pdf" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div>
    <!--Box Site Survey DDO-->
    <div class="boxindex2">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">Site Survey DDO</h1>
      <p class="Srouge statue">Privée</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">G:\Prive\SDO-OP\08-Modèles\_Site Survey\site survey DDO presentation générale.pptx</a></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/site survey DDO presentation générale.pptx" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div>
     <!--OLC modele Galileo-->
    <div class="boxindex3">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">Modèle OLC Galileo</h1>
      <p class="Srouge statue ">Privée</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">G:\Prive\SDO-OP\08-Modèles\_OLC modèle\OLC - VA244 GALILEO FOC-M8 1-3.docx</a></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/OLC - VA244 GALILEO FOC-M8 1-3.docx" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div>
     <!--Modele DM Galileo-->
    <div class="boxindex4">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">Modèle DM Galileo</h1>
      <p class="Srouge statue ">Privée</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">G:\Prive\SDO-OP\08-Modèles\_DM et SC activities 2018\VA244_GALILEO FOC Daily-meeting OPS_OHB_2018-06-21.docx</a></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/VA244_GALILEO FOC Daily-meeting OPS_OHB_2018-06-21.docx" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div>  
     <!--Modele M8 Galileo-->
    <div class="boxindex5">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">Modèle M8 Galileo</h1>
      <p class="Srouge statue ">Privée</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">G:\Prive\SDO-OP\08-Modèles\_DM et SC activities 2018\VA244-GALILEO FOC M8 -- DM One.docx</a></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/VA244-GALILEO FOC M8 -- DM One.docx" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div> 
     <!--Box "A INSERER"
    <div class="boxindex6">
      <h1 class="boxtitle animated fadeInUp delay-500ms">"À INSÉRER"</h1>
      <p class="statue ">Privée / Public</p>
      <p class="Svert links "><a class="Svert">\\</a></p>
      <p class="Sorange impt "></p>
      <a class="boxbtn" href="docs/" target="_blank">Obtenir</a>
    </div>-->

   </div>

  </div>

    <!--Formulaire-->
   <div class="formdiv" id="formulaire">
    <form>
        <h1 id="h1form">Ajouts d'Outils</h1>
        <label for="title">Titre de l'outil</label>:<input type="text" id="titleform" name="title"><br /><br />

        <label for="title">Entrez le chemin du nouvelle Outil</label>:<input type="text" id="chemin" name="chemin"><br /><br />

        <label for="title">Entrez le nom.lextension du fichier</label>:<input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br /><br />

        <label for="title">Entrez le Statue de votre Outil</label>:<input type="text" id="statue" name="statue"><br /><br />

        <label for="title">Affichage de l'Outil</label>:<select id="select" name="side" form="side">
        <option value="droite">Droite</option>
        <option value="gauche">Gauche</option>
        </select><br /><br />

        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="envoyer">
    </form>
  </div>   

</body>
</html>
```

I wish that when the user clicks on validate local storage stock all this information and then bring up code html and css (later) with the data he just entered and that the html code obviously remains on the page indefinitely .

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you open the dev tools (right click => inspect) and then go to the Application tab, you should be able to select Local Storage on the left. Do you see your values getting saved?

Comment: Please also add the HTML code so we can see what is each item you mention in your code.

Comment: It's added, the value getting saved in the local storage but if i do a "console.log(localStorage('titre');" the title didn't appears. Sorry for the English.

Comment: You have to do `localStorage.getItem('titre')` to get the value. To set values you have to use `localStorage.setItem('titre',val)` . You can refer API docs here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yes it's what i do.